# Google DataStudio - Date Ranges

Tags: looker-studio

I'm pretty new to dataStudio and I'm trying to build a simple dashboard with the billing data exported to bigQuery. The thing is that I added a bar chart to show current month expenses but it doesn't match my current bill, after a further investigation I realized the chart is including expenses from the last month as you can see in here:

[image: invoices]

The filter clearly shows the current month expenses but it still includes expenses from last month and not sure why. Also, how can I make a filter that considers `invoice.month` just in case there are some expenses that started on the last day of the previous month and were charged until the next day.

UPDATE # 1:

If I add usage_start_date and usage_end_date you will see that the filter is not working as expected because it considers days from the past month

[image: this_month]

UPDATE # 2:

It seems like selecting the field for date range dimension is not available to me for my data source (bigQuery dataset created by GCP from billing data), the same thing on both options: report settings and current page settings

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Summary

1. Create the **Calculated Field** below;
2. Ensure that the **Date Range Dimension** in the charts as well as Report (or Current Page) is set to the newly created Date Field.

### 1) Dates: TODATE & CONCAT

The `invoice.month` field is currently not a Google Data Studio recognised Date; creating the Data Source-level [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below will do the trick:

One approach is to use a complete **YYYYMMDD** Date, which can be achieved by using the [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) function to add a **Day** component (the 15th is used below), and then incorporating the [`TODATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) function to ensure that the Date format is recognised:

```
TODATE(CONCAT(invoice.month, "15"), "%Y%m%d", "%Y%m%d")
```

[image]

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e6a0ad51-dbc0-404f-8882-b933be1dea60) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

### 2) Dates: Date Range Dimension

Ensure that the **Date Range Dimension** in the chart as well as the the Report (or Current Page) is set to a Google Data Studio recognised Date Field; this can be achieved by:

**2.1) Report Settings**

- There are two ways to access Report Settings:

  - File > Report Settings;
  - Right click on a blank space on the page and select Report Settings from the Drop-down;

**2.2) Data Source**

- Select the respective Data Source;

**2.3) Date Range Dimension**

- Select the newly created Date Field from the list of fields.

Added a [New Page to the Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e6a0ad51-dbc0-404f-8882-b933be1dea60/page/z76WB) as well as a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

Comment: Wow, so amazing answer you provided @Nimantha, I'm tempted to accept your answer as correct but I made a mistake, just updated the question, would you please check it out?

Comment: Updated the Answer to include a second section on Report Settings (as well as a GIF to elaborate); Ensure that the Date Range Dimension in the chart as well as the the Report (or Current Page) is set to a Google Data Studio recognised Date Field

Comment: Sorry for keep asking @Nimantha. But for some reason, I don't see the data range dimension in the settings when I choose the data source (which is the exported data set that GCP creates in bigquery), just updated my question again so you can see it.

Comment: Just opened again my question as it seems there's a problem that can not be solved using the techniques you showed. Basically, there's no way for me to see Data Range Dimension field in any place

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the data source in question has enforced the date range to the partitioned column.

So, you can check this by editing the data source -> Edit connection, and check if the

> Use xxx as date range dimension

setting is on.